# Safety issue when using OneCare Safety Scanner - no description of "Issue" that is severe

Tags: firefox

Used Windows Onecare Safety Scanner several times and kept getting warning:

> 1 severe issue found and 1 high issue found.

No other info.... so what does it mean, and what do I do now?

Comment: Perhaps you should try _describing_ your problem, rather than assume that we have been looking over your shoulder or something? I, for one, am nowhere near Charleston.

Answer (score 0):

There are four possible severity ratings for NIS writeups:

> Critical - refers to a vulnerability whose exploitation could allow the propagation of an Internet worm without user action
>
> Important - refers to a vulnerability whose exploitation could result in compromise of the confidentiality, integrity, or availability of user’s data, or of the integrity or availability of processing resources
>
> Moderate - refers to a vulnerability whose exploitability is mitigated to a significant degree by factors such as default configuration, auditing, or difficulty of exploitation
>
> Low - refers to a vulnerability whose exploitation is extremely difficult, or whose impact is minimal